# Add corresponding elements in arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

What is the most compact way of adding corresponding elements of multiple arrays of same length  ?

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [5,5,5];
var c = [1,1,1];
resultant array should be [7,8,9]
```

I can do this with a simple for loop but could it be possible for jquery/lodash solution with minimum lines of code?

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: You can do this in a simple for loop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135874/element-wise-operations-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-go-through-an-array-and-add-their-values

Comment: Please try to understand the question before marking it as a duplicate and referring to links that are completely different questions.

Comment: @diEcho that's not the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Simple loop:

```
var result = [];
for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
 result.push(a[i]+b[i]+c[i]);
```

> **Note:** Assuming all array of same length 3.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w527oq08/)

Comment: Surely there's an easier way to do this with lodash

Answer (score 0):

Well i'm not sure what you mean by the word 'Compact', either reduced number of lines or increased performance.. but the most reasonable and recommended way of doing it is through a simple loop:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [5,5,5];
var c = [1,1,1];
var result = [];    
for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){result[i] = a[i]+b[i]+c[i];}
```

result will contain [7,8,9]