# Acess add function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

this add function was given to me as a template method for one of my assignments.

```
add(other) {

};
```

How do I add my two vectors using this function in my if statement. Here's the if statement. I don't really understand what the 'other' means.

```
let v3 = new Vector3();
let v4 = new Vector3();
v3.v = [0, 0, 0]
v4.v = [0, 0, 0]

if(... "add" ... ) {
      v3.v[0] = parseFloat(document.getElementById("v1-x").value) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("v2-x").value);
      v3.v[1] = parseFloat(document.getElementById("v1-x").value) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("v2-x").value);   
}
```

I have the vectors v1 (v1-x, v1-y) and v2 (v2-x, v2-y) saved and I want to add them using the add function and save the final vector as v3

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear to me what you are trying to do. Can you be more specific on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Vector3 is not a Javascript builtin, and you don't show it. Your add method seems to be a class method, but you don't show the class (Vector3)?

Comment: @clota974 OP seems to be trying to implement vector addition based on the names of stuff, but it's not clear how the code they posted relates.

Comment: What does the `add` function have to do with the rest of the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Element-wise Operations In Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135874/element-wise-operations-in-javascript)

Comment: It would be `const result = new Vector3; result.v[0] = this.v[0] + other.v[0]; //etc. return result;` but that's some awful code you're being asked to work with

Answer (score 0):

Very vague question but look at something like this. Better if you gave more information on the code and question though.

```
let v3 = [] // to represent a new vector
let v4 = [] // to represent a new vector
v3.v = [6, -2, 0]
v4.v = [-4, 4, 0]

function addTwoVectors(vectorOne, vectorTwo) {
  if (vectorOne.v.length === vectorTwo.v.length) {
    var result = []
    for (var i = 0; i < vectorOne.v.length; i++) {
      result.push(vectorOne.v[i] + vectorTwo.v[i])
    }
    return result
  }
}

const result = addTwoVectors(v3, v4)

console.log(result)
```